# Unable to view the WPF designer at design time

Tags: mvvm

I’m unable view the designer at designtime after adding GalaSoft.MvvmLight(Runtime version v2.0.50727, version 0.0.0.0) and GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras(Runtime v2.0.50727, version 0.0.0.0) dlls. I am getting this exception at design time.

> System.IO.FileLoadException Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.*nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef) at
>   MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.VsReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly
>   reflectionAssembly) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.CachingReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly
>   reflectionAssembly) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.IReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly
>   reflectionAssembly) at
>   MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetRuntimeMetadata(Object
>   reflectionMetadata) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.d*_c.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.GetAttributes(Assembly
>   assembly, Type attributeType, Func`2
>   reflectionMapper) at
>   MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetAttributes(ITypeMetadata
>   attributeType) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlAssembly.get_XmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata
>   sourceAssembly) at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensions.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata
>   source) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier
>   identifier) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope
>   parentScope, IParseContext context) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement
>   parent, PrefixScope parentScope,
>   IParseContext context,
>   IMarkupSourceProvider provider) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean
>   convertToXamlWithErrors) at
>   MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
>   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load() at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView
>   view) at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory
>   factory, IsolatedView view) at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory
>   factory, IsolatedView view) at
>   MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
>
> System.NotSupportedException An
>   attempt was made to load an assembly
>   from a network location which would
>   have caused the assembly to be
>   sandboxed in previous versions of the
>   .NET Framework. This release of the
>   .NET Framework does not enable CAS
>   policy by default, so this load may be
>   dangerous. If this load is not
>   intended to sandbox the assembly,
>   please enable the
>   loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569
>   for more information.

I am using .Net framework 4.0 ,WPF with c#.

Here my code

```
<Window x:Class="TreeviewApp.MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras" 
xmlns:dataGrid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> 
<Window.Resources> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="DetailTemplate"> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Swift_File_Name}"/> 
</DataTemplate> 
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MasterTemplate" 
ItemsSource="{ Binding SwiftCol,Mode=TwoWay}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DetailTemplate}"> 
<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle> 
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"> 
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
</Style> 
</HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CITA_Info_Id}"/> 
</HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
<!--<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem"> 
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
</Style>-->
　
　
　
　
<!--<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem"> 
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
</Style>-->
</Window.Resources> 
<Grid> 
<Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="428,0,0,0" Name="button1" Command="{Binding btnClick}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" /> 
<TreeView Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" 
x:Name="tvCita" ItemsSource="{Binding CitaCol,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}"> 
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"> 
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/> 
</Style> 
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
<i:Interaction.Triggers> 
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged"> 
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TreeviewItemClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName= tvCita, Mode=OneWay}"/> 
</i:EventTrigger> 
</i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</TreeView> 
<dataGrid:DataGrid Name="dgSwift" Margin="105,24,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = SwiftCol}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"> 
<dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns> 
<dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="0000" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_0000_count}"></dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn> 
<dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="1000" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1000_count}"></dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn> 
<dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="1100" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1100_Count}"></dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn> 
<dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="1110" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1110_count}"></dataGrid:DataGridTextColumn> 
</dataGrid:DataGrid.Columns> 
</dataGrid:DataGrid> 
</Grid> 
</
Window>
```

But, all the functionality is working fine. Please tell me how to fix this designer issue.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from the link in the error?  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714417/mvvm-light-toolkit-throws-an-system-io-fileloadexception

Answer (score 0):

the error occur in event trigger function . the reason design is not available in the design time. also some error in datagrid check with this code

```
<Window x:Class="TreeviewApp.MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras" 
xmlns:dataGrid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Swift_File_Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MasterTemplate" 
ItemsSource="{ Binding SwiftCol,Mode=TwoWay}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DetailTemplate}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CITA_Info_Id}">           
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="428,0,0,0" Name="button1" Command="{Binding btnClick}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <TreeView Height="288" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89"  x:Name="tvCita" ItemsSource="{Binding CitaCol,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!--<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                --><!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TreeviewItemClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName= tvCita, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>--><!--
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>-->
        </TreeView>
        <DataGrid Name="dgSwift" Margin="105,24,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = SwiftCol}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="0000" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_0000_count}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1000" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1000_count}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1100" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1100_Count}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="1110" Binding="{Binding Path = Line_1110_count}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```