# Visual Studio 2010 UnresolvedAssemblyException: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: log4net

Tags: wpf, exception, xaml, log4net

Recently, I've started to encounter exceptions in the Visual Studio 2010 WPF designer seemingly due to log4net.  If I freshly build my project, the XAML file will appear correctly in the designer.  Then, once I start to click on controls to jump within the XAML, this exception quickly gets thrown:

```
System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821.

at System.Reflection.Adds.AssemblyProxy.GetResolvedAssembly()
at System.Reflection.Adds.AssemblyProxy.GetHashCode()
continues...
```

The problem only goes away when I remove the log4net reference.  This is now the second project to exhibit this behavior.  Has anyone else seen this and/or found a fix?

**Note:** I'm using .NET 4 Full (not Client Profile) and I've toggled Specific Version on the log4net reference T/F to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide the code you added to your web.config to toggle the specific version?

Comment: No web.config, toggled Specific Version in the VS IDE property window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue after:

1. Finding [this blog](http://www.purelogic.ca/blog/matt/2010/10/13/visual-studio-2010-designer-exception-unresolvedassemblyexception.aspx) where the author resolved a similar situation by placing the unresolved assembly in the **Public Assemblies** folder (found using k3b's fuslogvw tool)
2. Encountering a `FileLoadException` which led me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714417/mvvm-light-toolkit-throws-an-system-io-fileloadexception).
3. Downloading a fresh copy of log4net, **unblocking** the zip file, and replacing the reference in VS and the Public Assemblies folder.

But, I'm still not sure why I had to place this particular assembly in the Public Assemblies folder.  All the other assemblies I reference don't require this step.

Comment: This error is driving me mad... I'm trying to use first solution, but I'm feeling a bit lost... can anybody illustrate on this??

Comment: What is the "first solution" - using Fuslogvw.exe that k3b mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Assembly Binding Log Viewer" (Fuslogvw.exe) that belongs to the dotnet sdk to find out which dll is loaded when and why . If logging is enabled it can show you wich assemblies are loaded and which assembly caused it to load.

For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.80).aspx

Sometimes the dll is there but in the wrong version.

if you include universe.dll into your project you must also include log4net.dll with local copy=true

Comment: I can't seem to get an answer from Fuslogvw.exe.  After I rebuild in VS 2010, the binding logs appear, but each one states: `The operation failed.  Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.`  This message appears in each log for each reference DLL whether I include/exclude log4net with no other info that looks revealing.

Comment: the log should contain info: Wich dll-requested log4net.dll and where the search took place. is log4net.dll in one of the searched directories? have you included log4net.dll with local copy=true in the gui-project?

Comment: I changed my settings to log to a custom path and "Log bind failures to disk".  Previously, I was logging all binds.  Now when I work in VS and the UnresolvedAssemblyException occurs, no errors appear in fuslogvw!  I can rebuild/experience exception multiple times and fuslogvw does not detect any bind errors...

Comment: log4net.dll is not in one of the searched directories, and I've toggled Copy Local to no effect.

Comment: How i would try to find it: Quit Vs2010; start Fuslogvw.exe (on win7 as admin). Select "Log bind failures to disk". Re-start Vs2010. after the errors occur press "Refresh" in Fuslogvw. Now you should see the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to your assembly "log4net" in the Project Properties/Reference Paths.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Assuming this works, you'd still have to do this for each project exhibiting this problem.

Comment: You can create a single .Targets file which has your reference to the log4net assembly.  In each project, you can then import the .Targets file, that way you can control the common references from a single point.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when we had this problem, it was due to the paths we used to add the references.

We are using some custom ".targets" files which define the references.  There are lots of mixed dependencies with the projects, and using the .targets files helps to keep the references defined in one place.

Well, the references HintPath ended up something like...

```
<HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\\Custom\CustomControlsWPF2.2011\Source\\..\Binaries\WPF\Custom.Windows.Controls.dll</HintPath>
```

When we removed the double blackslash, replacing with single "\", the "Visual Studio 2010 UnresolvedAssemblyException: Type universe cannot resolve assembly" error went away.

This is how is should have been.

```
<HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Custom\CustomControlsWPF2.2011\Source\..\Binaries\WPF\Custom.Windows.Controls.dll</HintPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your code runs at design time, as well as run time. If your code runs at design time, do not assume that Application.Current is your application. For example, when you are using Expression Blend, Current is Expression Blend. Typical operations that cause a custom control to fail at design time include the following.

```
-Casting Current to your custom subclass of Application.

-Using the FindName method on Current.

-Not checking whether Application.Current has returned a value that is null. If Visual Studio does not create an application object, then Application.Current may return null.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356886%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

give a try to this. add it at the beginig of your functions:

```
// Check for design mode. 
if ((bool)(System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue))
{
    return;
}
```